# Shopify custom post?

Tags: content-management-system, shopify

I want to start using Shopify but I still need to know if it is possible to create custom post type, a bit like wordpress : a new button on the admin panel where there is product, orders, customers, etc, where I could put a whole new kind of posts, for blogging or image gallery.

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 0):

You can't customise the administration panel of Shopify, with adding new buttons, for example. The only way is creating a browser extension as [Shopify FD](http://shopifyfd.com/). This extension add new buttons on the interface and other improvements.

You can add new "custom post type" as wordpress but it works different, looks at the ["building themes"](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development) shopify section.

Answer (score -1):

You are free to create blogs, and add articles to them, and you can create as many image galleries as you want. No limits to Shopify in that respect. Have fun!